# Work Around Unspecified Error in Windows App Certification Kit

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, vs-community-edition, wack

Could someone recommend some troubleshooting tips for the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) process when attempting to Create an App Package for the store?  The app package builds fine, however, when WACK starts it immediately crashes with an "Unspecified Error".

[image: WACK error]

I'm using VS Community and an Individual developer account.

I've tried uninstall WACK and re-installing, but it is integrated in VS Community, so no luck there.  I have also tried side-loading the app, but the PowerScript (PS) fails.  Checking the PS log it states, "The specific error text for this failure is: Unspecified error."

Comment: did you check the event logs? Anything there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but deleting the AppPackages, bin, BundleArtifacts and obj folder before running the Store Certification fixed the issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I basically cleared all my build files and tried to create the App Store package again: Same error.  Were there any tricks that may have helped with the workaround?

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Must be a separate issue.  That's really my irk; "unspecified error" is broad.  I worked around the issue by using a different machine to complete the package